How to do join in a SQL query using a bit masked value
I am have trouble finding a good example SQL query to do a join on two tables where the value being joined on is a bit mask value.
Region Table



RegionBitmask
RegionName




1
North


2
East


4
South


8
West



Store Region XRef Table



StoreID
StoreCode
StoreRegion




1
100
3


2
101
1


3
102
9


4
103
8


5
104
12



Such that I would get results back like:



StoreID
StoreCode
StoreRegion
RegionBitmask
RegionName




1
100
3
1
North


1
100
3
2
East


2
101
1
1
North


3
102
9
1
North


3
102
9
8
West


4
103
8
8
West


5
104
12
4
South


5
104
12
8
West



select *
from StoreRegionXRef
     left join Region on StoreRegion & RegionBitmask = StoreRegion

Does not provide expected results, always seem to get a subset of expected results or no results.

Why are you using a bitmask and not a proper many to many relationship?

I believe something like from StoreRegionXRef left join Region on StoreRegion & RegionBitmask = 1 would you get you in the ballpark. Probably won't be the speediest of joins if you have a lot of data.

StoreRegion & RegionBitmask > 0 is usually the way to do it

>0 makes more sense

"Does not provide expected results..." -- Please include the expected results.

@Thom A Sorry I am unclear if you are being snarky, but if you have a suggestion for better representing such a data structure then please point to an example rather than just making noise.

@siggemannen Thanks for the help. That's obvious to me now! I would give you a +1 but don't have ability to do so yet due to my low rep.

Snarky? No, take my question at face value: Why are you using a bitmask and not a proper many to many relationship?

@Thom A Ok, glad for any chance to be enlightened, but I fail to see how a many to many relationship is proper for a bitmask. The data in the tables in my original question are simplified for brevity (only 4 bits used in bitmask). The real data I am using will use up to 28 bits for various flags. I don't see how a table with precomputed values with all possible combinations containing 268,435,455 rows makes it "proper". But I would be glad to be shown any proof of a better solution for my own or anyone else's self-improvement if you care to elaborate with detail.

There's plenty out there on the subject. A quick search gave me this answer, for example.

Using the & (bitwise AND) operator you can join between your StoreRegionXref and StoreRegion table:
SELECT *
from StoreRegionXRef 
  left join StoreRegion on StoreRegionXref.StoreRegion & StoreRegion.RegionBitmask > 0

You can see a dbfiddle of this in action here
This logic checks your bitmask to see if the corresponding bit in your StoreRegion table is present in the bitmask.

@copperhead did this answer your question?

@JNevill Thanks, for helping to clarify my now obvious mistake!
